# App not shown up in Google Play Store search results

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Five days ago, my app was published by Google. With direct link everything works fine, but if I search the app with the exact title, the app is not shown in the results, not even if I scroll all the way down. It's not an app compatibility issue with my devices, it cannot be found as well on anonymous browser sessions.

Few month ago, I developed a similar app, which can be found nicely. I double checked everything, they are almost the same. I have no idea why my new app is not shown in results and there is no Google contact I could ask this.

Works fine if you search for "Bitcoin Node Observer" at this 
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ceaver.bno)

Not listed in result search for "Bitcoin Address Observer"at this
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ceaver.bao)

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's listed now... 8 days later.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the given links and both of those lead to different apps from the same publisher
Seems like you have published the app recently, it generally takes 4-8 days for the app to be indexed.
Try using better SEO for the app to be listed better.
Refer this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6041489?hl=en) for more about app indexing.

Comment: Yes... that's me. But one app can be found if you type the tile in the search bar and the other not.

Comment: @ThomasKayser Sometimes it takes time for app to be indexed.

Comment: yah but... 5 days?

Comment: @ThomasKayser You may follow this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6041489?hl=en) to know more about app indexing

Comment: according to your link, app indexing has nothing to do with store search result: "With App Indexing, users who have installed your app can open links from Google mobile search directly in your app."

Comment: Did you try reaching the support team? Can find the app with `pub: Thomas Kayser` too.

Comment: I couldn't find any e-mail or contact form at all in the google play console

Answer (score 0):

Did you try searching it by it's app package name?

Comment: What is it good for? People will not search with the package name.

Comment: Just to see if it's even listed. If not give it some more time or just try uploading it again. Also playing around with keywords might help. Google is weird sometimes

Comment: It is listed, I posted the direct link, have a look at my request again. But it's not listed in search results. And people don't have the direct link, so how can it ever be found.

Comment: I meant listed in terms of listed under search results. It should definitely appear there by searching with it's package name. If not, as already said, it would probably be the best to temporarily take it down, change the discription/keywords and upload it again